# Effective gain when stacking N frame images

Tags: observational-astronomy, photometry, image-processing, ccd

I am trying to understand how to derive the effective gain in [electrons / ADU] when stacking N frame images in different (summed, averaged, or medianed) ways. I found the  effective gains for the three kinds of stacking methods on page 20 in [IRAF/DAOPHOT user's manual](https://iraf.net/irafdocs/daorefman.pdf).

1. The image is the sum of N frames:
   **effective gain = gain**
2. The image is the average of N frames: **effective gain = N * gain**
3. The image is the median of N frames: **effective gain = 2.0 * N * gain / 3**

To calculate photometry errors, I need to take these effective gains into consideration.
I would appreciate if you explain how to derive these results. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the last one must be some kind of approximation. The median of N frames should approach the average when $N$ is large. Please can you point to a page number in the document your referenced.

Comment: @ProfRob Thank you for your comment. I see, it seems the result of median stacking is somewhat tricky. It says on the page 20 (I added it to the main text).